# How to swipe NSArray of images in Order using ISwipeGesture iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, swipe-gesture

Hi in my application i have array of images i want to view image by swipe so i have used the Swipe Gesture in my application for both left and right but the problem is its not showing the images in order its just showing two images only please tell me how to resolve this issue.

My swipe code.

```
- (IBAction)handleswipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

       //NSLog(@"swiped");
       int imageIndex = 3;
      NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                               @"2.jpg",
                                               @"3.jpg",
                                               @"4.jpg",
                                          @"5.jpg", nil];

     UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender direction];
     switch (direction) {
         case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
               imageIndex++;
               break;
         case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
              imageIndex--;
              break;
           default:
              break;
        }
     imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0 )? ([images count] -1):
     imageIndex % [images count];
     imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];   
    }
```

I have added the Swipe Gesture in image view and i have set one image already in imageview but its not showing in order its only showing two images in randomly please tell me where I'm doing wrong and how to resolve this one.

Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve this by UIScrollView also.

Comment: Just to understand the context of the issue, do you have a UIImageView with a swipe gesture attached to it. Every time a swipe is registered it calls the method above, is this correct?

Comment: @bennythemink  ya excatly

Answer (score 0):

```
right_gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(method)];
        right_gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [objSecondView.view addGestureRecognizer:right_gesture];
        right_gesture.delegate = self;
```

and in method...

```
if (varSecondCount==3) {
}
else{

    varSecondCount++;
switch (varSecondCount) {
        case 0:
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rcz_img1.png"]];
break;
case 1:
   [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rcz_img2.png"]];
break;
case 2:
   [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rcz_img3.png"]];
break;
case 3:
   [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rcz_img4.png"]];
break;
case 4:
   [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"step2_5.png"]];
break;

default:
break;
}
```

hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented same thing in my app here is code for that: **imageIndxMain** is global variable holding current index of array

```
if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
{
        if (imageIndxMain==0)
            return;
        else
        {
            CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
            transition.duration = .40;
            transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
            transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
            transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
            transition.delegate = self;
            [imagescrollview.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

            UIImage *img1;
            imageIndxMain--;

            ImgView.image=[imageArray objectAtIndex:imageIndxMain];

        }}else if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
{

        if (imageIndxMain == ([imageArray count] - 1))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
            transition.duration = .40;
            transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
            transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
            transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
            transition.delegate = self;
            [imagescrollview.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
            UIImage *img1;

            imageIndxMain++;
             ImgView.image=[imageArray objectAtIndex:imageIndxMain];


        }

    }
```